TypeError: _form_form_component__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_57__ is undefined
I am working on an Angular-project where my current task is to turn all components standalone. However one component is not playing nicely and throws this error in the console:
TypeError: _form_form_component__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_57__ is undefined
Note that this error only occurs in the console in the browser after starting the application, the bundle gets build without any issues. All other components are already standalone and work fine, this component is the only (and last one) that does not play nicely.
The code of the component looks like this:
import { Component, Input, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { DownloadService, DynatraceService } from '@enercity/ap-core';
import { CellValue, Column, Workbook } from 'exceljs';
import { cloneDeep } from 'lodash-es';
import {
  ApUiButtonComponent,
  ApUiButtonsComponent,
  ApUiFormComponent,
  ApUiModalComponent,
  FormConfig,
} from '../../components';
import { ToastService } from '../../services/toast.service';
import { ApUiDatatableComponent } from '../datatable/datatable.component';

interface FormValue {
  fileType: 'excel' | 'csv';
  rowCount: number;
  columnIds: string[];
}

@Component({
  selector: 'ui-datatable-export-modal',
  templateUrl: './datatable-export-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./datatable-export-modal.component.scss'],
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ApUiButtonComponent, ApUiButtonsComponent, ApUiFormComponent, ApUiModalComponent],
})
export class ApUiDatatableExportModalComponent<Row, Filter, SubtableRow> implements OnInit {
  @Input() public datatable!: ApUiDatatableComponent<Row, Filter, SubtableRow>;

  @ViewChild('form') public form?: ApUiFormComponent<FormValue>;
  @ViewChild('modal') public modal?: ApUiModalComponent;

  public initialValue: Partial<FormValue> = {};
  public loading = false;
  public formConfig?: FormConfig<FormValue>;

  constructor(
    private downloadService: DownloadService,
    private toast: ToastService,
    private dynatrace: DynatraceService,
  ) {}

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    if (!this.datatable) {
      throw new Error('DatatableExportModalComponent: invalid input - datatable is missing');
    }
    const visibility = this.datatable.columnVisibility.state;
    this.initialValue = {
      columnIds:
        this.datatable.config?.columns
          .map((column, index) => {
            if (visibility.includes(column.property)) {
              return index.toString();
            }
            return 'invisible';
          })
          .filter((item) => item !== 'invisible') ?? [],
      fileType: 'excel',
      rowCount: 1000,
    };
    this.formConfig = {
      sections: [
        {
          description: this.datatable.i18n.texts.exportingModalFormDescription,
          rows: [
            {
              controls: [
                {
                  type: 'RADIOS',
                  property: 'fileType',
                  trackId: `${this.datatable.config?.uniqueId}-file-type`,
                  texts: {
                    label: this.datatable.i18n.texts.exportingModalFiletypeLabel,
                  },
                  validators: [Validators.required],
                  orientation: 'VERTICAL',
                  options: [
                    {
                      value: 'excel',
                      text: this.datatable.i18n.texts.exportingModalExcelOptionText,
                    },
                    {
                      value: 'csv',
                      text: this.datatable.i18n.texts.exportingModalCSVOptionText,
                    },
                  ],
                },
              ],
            },
            {
              controls: [
                {
                  type: 'NUMBERFIELD',
                  property: 'rowCount',
                  trackId: `${this.datatable.config?.uniqueId}-row-count`,
                  texts: {
                    label: this.datatable.i18n.texts.exportingModalRowCountLabel,
                  },
                  validators: [Validators.required, Validators.min(0), Validators.max(10000)],
                  min: 0,
                  max: 10000,
                  step: 1000,
                },
              ],
            },
            {
              controls: [
                {
                  type: 'CHECKBOXES',
                  viewType: 'SWITCH',
                  property: 'columnIds',
                  trackId: `${this.datatable.config?.uniqueId}-column-ids`,
                  orientation: 'VERTICAL',
                  allOptionEnabled: true,
                  texts: {
                    label: this.datatable.i18n.texts.exportingModalVisibleColumnsLabel,
                  },
                  options: this.datatable.viewParser.headings,
                },
              ],
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    };
  }

  public async export(value: Partial<FormValue>): Promise<void> {
    if (this.datatable.config) {
      try {
        let rows: (string | number)[][];
        if (
          this.datatable.settings.features.serverSideProcessing &&
          value.rowCount &&
          value.fileType
        ) {
          this.loading = true;
          const params = cloneDeep(this.datatable.serverSide.params);
          if (params.pagination) {
            params.pagination.limit = value.rowCount;
            params.pagination.offset = 0;
          }
          const result = await this.datatable.serverSide.performFetch(
            params,
            this.datatable.filter.value,
          );
          rows = this.datatable.dataitemService.transformMultiConfigsAndValues(
            result.data,
            this.datatable.config.columns,
          );
        } else {
          rows = this.datatable.dataitemService.transformMultiConfigsAndValues(
            this.datatable.data,
            this.datatable.config.columns,
          );
        }
        if (value.rowCount && rows.length > value.rowCount) {
          rows.length = value.rowCount;
        }
        this.processViewAppearances(rows);
        rows = rows.map((row) =>
          row.filter((item, index) => value.columnIds?.includes(index.toString())),
        );
        const headings = this.datatable.viewParser.headings
          .map((item) => item.text)
          .filter((item, index) => value.columnIds?.includes(index.toString()));
        if (value.fileType === 'csv') {
          this.exportCSV(rows, headings);
        } else if (value.fileType === 'excel') {
          await this.exportExcel(rows, headings);
        }
      } catch {
        this.dynatrace.reportError(
          `ap-ui: Datatable ${this.datatable.config?.uniqueId} - error during ${value.fileType} export`,
        );
        this.toast.showError({
          message: this.datatable.i18n.texts.exportingModalErrorToastMessage,
        });
      }
      this.modal?.close();
      this.loading = false;
    }
  }

  private processViewAppearances(rows: (string | number)[][]): void {
    if (this.datatable.config) {
      const columns = this.datatable.config.columns;
      for (const row of rows) {
        for (let i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
          const viewConfig = columns[i].view;
          if (viewConfig?.type === 'COUNT') {
            const count = this.sanitizedCount(row[i]);
            row[i] = `${count} ${
              count === 1
                ? this.datatable.translateOrNotPipe.transform(
                    viewConfig.texts.singularKey,
                    viewConfig.texts.singular,
                  )
                : this.datatable.translateOrNotPipe.transform(
                    viewConfig.texts.pluralKey,
                    viewConfig.texts.plural,
                  )
            }`;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  private sanitizedCount(value: string | number): number {
    if (typeof value === 'string') {
      const parsed = parseInt(value, 10);
      if (!isNaN(parsed)) return parsed;
    }
    if (typeof value === 'number') {
      if (!isNaN(value)) return value;
    }
    return 0;
  }

  private exportCSV(rows: (string | number)[][], headings: string[]): void {
    const content = `"${headings.join('","')}"\n`.concat(
      rows.map((row) => `"${row.join('","')}"`).join('\n'),
    );
    this.downloadService.download(content, `download.csv`);
  }

  private async exportExcel(rows: (string | number)[][], headings: string[]): Promise<void> {
    const workbook = this.createWorkbook(rows, headings);

    // Write workbook data to buffer
    const buffer = await workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer();

    // Trigger download of the Excel file
    this.downloadService.downloadBlob(new Blob([buffer]), 'download.xlsx');
  }

  private createWorkbook(rows: (string | number)[][], headings: string[]): Workbook {
    const workbook = new Workbook();
    const sheet = workbook.addWorksheet('Download');
    sheet.columns = headings.map((item) => ({ header: item }));
    for (const row of rows) {
      sheet.addRow(row);
    }

    // Iterate over each column to set data type for numeric cells (exceljs sees numbers as strings)
    sheet.columns.forEach((column: Partial<Column>, index: number) => {
      const columnValues = column.values;
      if (columnValues) {
        columnValues.forEach((value: CellValue, rowIndex: number): void => {
          const cell = sheet.getCell(rowIndex + 1, index + 1);
          if (cell.value != null && cell.value !== '') {
            const cellValue = cell.value.toString();

            // Check if the value has leading zeros
            const hasLeadingZeros = /^0\d+/.test(cellValue);

            // Check if the value is large enough to be written in scientific notation
            const needsScientificNotation = !isNaN(Number(cellValue)) && Number(cellValue) >= 1e15;

            if (hasLeadingZeros || needsScientificNotation) {
              cell.value = cellValue;
            } else if (!isNaN(Number(cellValue))) {
              cell.value = Number(cellValue);
              if (typeof cell.value === 'number') {
                cell.numFmt = '0';
              }
            }
          }
        });
      }
    });

    // Dynamically adjust column widths based on content length
    sheet.columns.forEach((column: Partial<Column>) => {
      if (column.values) {
        const lengths =
          column.values.map((v: CellValue) => {
            const typedV = v as string | number;
            return typedV?.toString().length ?? 0;
          }) ?? [];
        const maxLength = Math.max(...lengths.filter((v: number) => typeof v === 'number'));
        column.width = maxLength;
      }
    });

    return workbook;
  }
}

The full error in the console is
Uncaught TypeError: _form_form_component__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_57__ is undefined
    ApUiFormComponent main.js:10528
    31619 datatable-export-modal.component.ts:27
    31619 datatable-export-modal.component.ts:240
    Webpack 17
        __webpack_require__
        57317
        __webpack_require__
        14874
        __webpack_require__
        98918
        __webpack_require__
        50635
        __webpack_require__
        84429
        __webpack_require__
        __webpack_exec__
        <anonymous>
        O
        <anonymous>
        webpackJsonpCallback
        <anonymous>
main.js:10528:70
    ApUiFormComponent main.js:10528
    31619 datatable-export-modal.component.ts:27
    31619 datatable-export-modal.component.ts:240
    Webpack 17
        __webpack_require__
        57317
        __webpack_require__
        14874
        __webpack_require__
        98918
        __webpack_require__
        50635
        __webpack_require__
        84429
        __webpack_require__
        __webpack_exec__
        <anonym>
        O
        <anonym>
        webpackJsonpCallback
        <anonym>

Line 27 is the imports-array, specifically ApUiFormComponent, line 240 is private createWorkbook(rows: (string | number)[][], headings: string[]): Workbook {

please share the full stacktrace if possible a stackblitz where the issue happens, with minimal code.

I added some more information to the post, I hope this helps. Unfortunately I am not able to provide a Stackblitz-example, apologies for that

This kind of issues mostly arrises because of cyclic dependencies.
I recommend using madge to detect your cyclic imports. Then it's up to you to solve them.
